# Is possible to limit a row selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a button to delete just one row from a table on Excel using vba but when I press the button and select more than just one row or a lot of cells then deletes everything, I want to limit the selection from E to I (and no matters the number of row)
Here is my code and thanks a lot, hope you can help me, I don't find anything similar yet.

```
Sub delete_a_row()
Dim variable As Range


 On Error GoTo local_err
     CONFIRM = MsgBox("do you wanna delete a row?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "delete row")
        If (CONFIRM = vbYes) Then

                Set variable = Application.InputBox("select a row", "delete row", , , , , , 8)
                Range(variable.Address).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        End If
local_err:
End Sub
```

I know looks kinda messy, sorry for that I'm new on VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Limited Row Selection

- The following will delete the first `row` of the `first range`
  (if non-contiguous) of the `selection` from columns `E` to `I`.
- What I mean by `first range` is if you select a range starting with row `6` and press
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and select another range starting with row `2`, then
  row `6` will be deleted (See [Range.Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.areas)).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub delete_a_row()
    Dim Confirm
    On Error GoTo local_err
    Confirm = MsgBox("do you wanna delete a row?", _
                     vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "delete row")
    If (Confirm = vbYes) Then
        Dim variable As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set variable = Application.InputBox("select a row", _
                                            "delete row", , , , , , 8)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            On Error GoTo local_err
            With variable
                Range(Cells(.Row, "E"), Cells(.Row, "I")).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End With
        Else
            On Error GoTo local_err
            MsgBox "User cancelled."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "User selected No."
    End If
local_err:
End Sub
```

Comment: ```MsgBox "User cancelled."``` after ```On Error GoTo local_err``` seems odd? Maybe they should be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want deleted is columns **E** through **I** then:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim variable As Range, rw As Long

    Set variable = Application.InputBox("select a row", "delete row", , , , , , 8)
    rw = variable(1).Row

    Range(Cells(rw, "E"), Cells(rw, "I")).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

This code will remove cells from only a single row.

Comment: Is still letting me select more than E to I, If the user select (For example) "D to I" then the program will say "Hey dude you can't delete this, is exceding the range" but Thanks Gary, I can apply part of the code for make it better =D